# Integration with binomial form from Gradshteyn

Tags: integration

${\int x^n z^m_k dx} ={x^{n+1}z^m_k \over {km+n+1}}+{{amk \over km+n+1} \int x^n z^{m-1}_k }dx $

where $z^m_k = (a+bx^k)$

How can I solve this kind of problem?
need some hint.

Comment: Do you mean Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, the enormous book of series and integrals? They usually give a coded reference for each entry

Comment: i have no idea about this reference!
is there any link or something?

Comment: Atiqur, you used the name Gradshteyn in your title, so we're trying to understand what you meant by that.  At a glance it looks like it might be proved by "integration by parts".

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int x^n(a+bx^k)^m dx =\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} (a+bx^k)^m -\frac{kmb}{n+1} \int x^{n+k}(a+bx^k)^{m-1} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that the second intergral can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 b\int x^{n+k}(a+bx^k)^{m-1} dx= \int x^{n}(-a+a+bx^k)(a+bx^k)^{m-1} dx \\= -a \int x^{n}(a+bx^k)^{m-1} dx +\int x^n(a+bx^k)^m dx. 
\end{eqnarray*}
The second integral is the integral on the LHS of the first equation; the result now follows using a little bit of linear algebra.

Comment: You are awesome man. I was stuck with this two integrals for almost four days. You are lovely!